# Line spacing inside quote environment

Tags: line-spacing, quoting, setspace

I use the `setspace` package to set double spacing throughout the document. It also sets double spacing inside the `quote` environment. But, I want one half space inside the `quote` environment. How can this be done?

EDIT 1:
If changing font size and font type is also included with the answers, then this Q&A thread will be little more comprehensive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the [setspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package you can use `\doublespacing` for your document and `\onehalfspacing` inside the `quote` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\onehalfspacing
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If you want this spacing for all the `quote` environments, then a simple redefinition of the environment will do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\onehalfspacing}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think yours does add some different value in the automation. For the user: Note that it holds for *all* `quote` environments after it is used.

Comment: Redefining the environment did the trick for a document that used custom text styles for spacing, without requiring me to define yet another text style.

Comment: When I adjust the spacing inside the quote environment, I get an extra white space above the quote. Any idea what's causing that? I'm working in amsart, in case that's relevant.

Comment: @twofeet please feel free to open a follow-up question.

Answer (score 10):

Shameless plug: Use my [quoting](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package and its `font` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[font=onehalfspacing]{quoting}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
% <-- to prevent first-line indentation of the following environment
\begin{quoting}
\blindtext
\end{quoting}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `quote` environment provides a group within which you can modify the `\doublespacing` (from the [`setspace` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace)) to whatever you want. In this case, just add `\onehalfspacing` in the `quote` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\doublespacing% <--- Global line spacing
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
  \onehalfspacing% <--- Local line spacing
  \lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Different spacing in quote environment]

In addition to modifying the local line spacing within the `quote` environment, you can include any font-related commands. For example, using

```
\onehalfspacing\small\itshape% Localized font modification
```

will typeset the `quote` in small, italicized font:

[image: Modified font in quote environment]