# Line spacing inside quote environment in amsart (removing extra white space)

Tags: line-spacing, quoting, amsart, setspace

This is a follow-up to [Line spacing inside quote environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29699/27635). I'm using the `amsart` document class, with a specifically defined line-spacing for the whole document. When I adjust the line-spacing within the `quote` environment, I get extra white space above the quoted material, as in the example below. Any idea how I can keep that from happening? Thanks.

Edit: On closer inspection it looks like the quote environment standardly inserts a little extra space between the main text and the quote, in order to set off the quote a bit. I'm OK with that extra space, but I want it to be added to the spacing *of the main text* rather than to that of the quote. If the extra margin is e, the main text is spaced at m, and the quote is spaced at q, I want the spacing between the main text and the quote to be m + e, not q + e.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstretch{1.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{quote}
\singlespacing
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surround the `quote` environment with a `spacing` environment with a `1` factor; additionally, to meet the new criterion in the edit to the question, you need to correct the spacing before and after the environment:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\doublespacing

\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}
  {\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}\begin{spacing}{1}\oldquote}
  {\oldendquote\end{spacing}\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the example I used `\doublespacing` instead of the original `\setstretch{1.15}` just to make the results more visible, but the original settings will also produce the requested result.

Comment: Thanks, but that applies the single-spacing both above and below the quote. What I want is for the spacing between the quote and the main text to match the spacing of the main text. The difference may not be visible with the document spacing set to 1.15, but it becomes visible when it's set to say, 2.

Comment: @twofeet perhaps ypu should mention that in your question, so it's clear to everyone.

Comment: @twofeet please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that makes the spacing between the main text and the quote match that of the main text. Do you happen to know the unit of extra space that the quote environment standardly inserts in order to set off the quote, so that I can add that manually if I want?

Answer (score 3):

`\singlespacing` will by design insert additional space when switching to it. Replace it with `\setstretch{1}`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstretch{1.15}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{quote}
\setstretch{1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Here's how to apply this change in the preamble instead of adding `\setstretch{1}` to every `quote` environment in your document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\setstretch{1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Output for both examples:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I notice that this leaves too little space between the main text and the first line of the block quote. That is, it applies the single-spacing to the space above the quote. This shows up more clearly if you set the document spacing to 2 and the quote-environment spacing to 1. 

Also, I could not get the preamble version to compile. \AtBeginEnvironment is showing up as an undefined control sequence (I'm using the standard TeXShop installation).